# Navigation Architecture Component - BottomNavigationView with Login Screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have my MainActivity setup which looks like this :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.host.HostActivity">



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainNavigationFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the bottom navigation has 3 tabs which can only be shown after some initial authentication and setup user calls have been performed.

What is the best way to show a Loading/Setting up user screen before I let user start using the bottom nav view.

One way I am thinking is to delay the setup of NaHostFragment in my Activity until all the setup is done. 
So basically toggle the visibility of `mainNavigationFragment` and `BottomNavigationView` till the setup is completed.

Are there any other ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [NavigationUI documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events) actually uses hiding a `BottomNavigationView` as its example. You could also use an `OnDestinationChangedListener` to update the visibility of your `BottomNavigationView`, say, only hiding it while the user is on the login screen (note that as per the [Conditional Navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional), you shouldn't be doing this in the start destination of your graph, but redirecting users to those screens):

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
  if(destination.parent?.id == R.id.login) {
    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
  } else {
    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks the part I am stuck with while trying to follow your answer is where does my Loading screen sits ? Should it be a Loading fragment which will be the Home for my nav graph and based on the livedata responses I toggle the bottom nav view and navigate the the first tab on bottom nav view when all my user setup is completed ? Or the loading should just be a plain view on my activity at same level as nav host ?

Comment: Also could you point out where the documentation says it should not be done as part of start destination ? The reason I ask I need to perform the user setup on every screen launch instead of button click as mentioned in the example of conditional navigation, hence I don't have a start dummy fragment per say. My start fragment is the first tab on my bottom view.

Comment: @duskandawn - see the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) which specifically calls this out. Yeah, if you're always blocking every screen, doing it at the activity level and [programmatically adding the NavHostFragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic) would be another option.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake for the pointers. Seems using the combination of `addOnDestinationChangedListener` and a new loadFragment in my nav_graph. I am able to show the loading screen before the main bottom nav views.

Comment: i was going with nested navigation graph, total overkill.

Answer (score 0):

in my Activity

```
//using view model
    loginViewModel.isLoggedIn.observe(this, Observer { loggedIn ->
                if(!loggedIn) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,LoginActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                }
                else {
//set up the controller
                    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                    nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
                    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
                        when(destination.id) {
                            R.id.navigation_home,R.id.navigation_profile,R.id.navigation_account -> {
                                nav_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }
                            else -> {
                                nav_view.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for Viewmodel the one that you are using